# Create a new app registration and user flow in an existing Azure B2C Tenant with IaC

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, infrastructure-as-code

I have an **Azure B2C tenant** where I need to create some **app registrations** and a new **user flow**.

I'm trying to do this with Terraform, but I can't find much documentation for doing this kind of stuff (I've only really found `azurerm_aadb2c_directory` to create a directory, but like I said, I already have one). I was wondering if using `azuread_application` is the right thing to do, and if so, how can I create the application registration in the B2C tenant instead of the main one.

Another question I have is if it's possible to create user flows in IaC. I haven't found any documentation on this.

I'm open to using another IaC tool that does the job easier if it's very difficult to do in Terraform.

**Is there a way to do this in Terraform or in another IaC tool/Azure Templates?**

Comment: Are you okay to make use of PowerShell or Rest API to create application and user flows?

Comment: I prefer a proper iac tool/cdk/template for that but if there is no other way a script should do the work as well

Comment: Can I post the solution using PowerShell script?

Comment: Sure thing, go ahead. Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an **Azure AD B2C application**, use the below PowerShell script:

```
# Connect to Microsoft Graph using the Connect-MgGraph cmdlet
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.ReadWrite.All"

# Define the parameters for the application
$displayName = "B2CAppPowershell"

#Define the request body for the application
$body = @{
    displayName = $displayName
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Define the headers for the request
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Define the URI for the request
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications"

# Send the request to create the application
$response = Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body

# Print the response
$response
```

[image]

***The Azure AD B2C application created successfully:***

[image]

To create the **Azure AD B2C user flow**, use the below PowerShell script:

*To create other user flows, refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identitycontainer-post-b2cuserflows?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)*

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "IdentityUserFlow.ReadWrite.All"

# Define the parameters for the user flow
$userFlowId = "testruk"
$userFlowType = "signUpOrSignIn"
$userFlowTypeVersion = 3

# Define the request body for the user flow
$body = @{
    id = $userFlowId
    userFlowType = $userFlowType
    userFlowTypeVersion = $userFlowTypeVersion
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Define the headers for the request
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Define the URI for the request
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/b2cUserFlows"

# Send the request to create the user flow
$response = Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Method Post -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body

# Print the response
$response
```

[image]

***The User flow got created successfully:***

[image]

**References:**

[Azure AD B2C Support · Issue #175 · hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread · GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/175#issuecomment-582707395) by Hayden Hao

[Automating Azure AD B2C tenancy deployments for your app (makerx.com.au)](https://blog.makerx.com.au/automating-azure-ad-b2c-tenancy-deployments-for-your-app/) by Trent Steenholdt